# Asp GridView Pagination custom CSS works in Design View but not in browser

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I'm using Bootstrap and have got a custom css link for the pagination in a gridview and all the of the CSS works from both pages, my master page has this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In the aspx page I have something along the lines of..

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grid_view_search" runat="server" onprerender="GridView_PreRender" DataSourceID="sql_data_source_search" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True">
            <Columns>
               //Columns here
            </Columns>
            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-bootstrap" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

This has all worked and is styled correctly apart from the "pagination-bootstrap" which in a browser just looks like the standard style for gridview (i.e. `12`) however in the design view it is loaded the way it is meant to look (i.e. `[1][2]`)

I've been playing around with it and tried putting the style in the gridview opening tag line. Online I only found answers where the links to the css file or images were starting with "~/css" but I don't believe it is that as the other bits I added to the style.css file are working perfectly fine.

Any help will be much appreciated

[Edit] Added images of what it looks like in design view and in a browser

Design View:
[image: Design View]

Browser:
[image: Browser]

Comment: I had another look on the bootstrap docs and I thought that was the right way of using the bootstrap css class? Is there a different way to ensure it is using bootstrap?

Comment: The bootstrap document is correct. I deleted my prior comment.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer was that the CSS was being cached so in order to refresh the page to get the updated CSS file I had to press Ctrl-F5 which then reloaded the page with the proper style for the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check out this article "Use Bootstrap Pagination On Gridview"
https://sufiawan.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/asp-net-use-bootstrap-pagination-on-gridview/

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it by adding it (and then renaming the ys to bootstrap `.pagination-bootstrap`) But it is still producing the same result.